# Mockito test failing to initialize

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mocking, mockito

This fails with InitializationError. Other tests in the same package run so I have done something silly in my code. Stacktrace reads "No tests found matching [[Exactmatch]]".

```
public class TestClassToTest {
    @Mock
    File mockOfAFile;

    @Test
    public void testAMethod(File mockOfAFile) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        given(fileMock.getName()).willReturn("test1");
        assertEquals("test1",ClassBeingTested.methodBeingTested(mockOfAFile));
    }
}
```

Have tried everything but am very new to Mockito. What silly thing am I doing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try removing `File mockOfAFile` from you test method signature and keep no parameters?

Comment: Also, can you try annotating your test class with `@UnitTest`

Comment: Can tell us how you're running them and attach the actual stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two things to fix:

1. The `@Test` method should have no parameters
2. You need another `File` instance, called `fileMock`.

So here is the updated code:

```
public class TestClassToTest {

    @Mock
    File mockOfAFile;

    @Mock
    File fileMock; // the new mock

    @Test
    public void testAMethod() { // no parameters
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        given(fileMock.getName()).willReturn("test1"); // here is the new mock used
        assertEquals("test1",ClassBeingTested.methodBeingTested(mockOfAFile));
    }
}
```